# Import in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, import

I have seen several imports here: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/svg/axis.js

If I try to search for documentation about how that may be made all the results I get are of the kind: "there is no import in Javascript". Example: [How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-to-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

I am guessing it is a node.js thing, but I've seen `require` used and not `import`, so this may be a different framework or tool.

How is this possible? It looks quite cool. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D3 is indeed using [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/) running a [dev package](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/package.json#L40) named [Smash](https://npmjs.org/package/smash) that converts those `import` into concatenated files.